# Comparing list of class by string length and text comparison

Tags: vb.net, list, compare

I have a List(Of Abbreviation).
The class "Abbreviation" contains the string members "Input", "Output" and "CaseSensitive".

The class is stated below.

I would like to sort this list so that the class with the "Input"

```
 "ZZZ"
```

comes before

```
 "zz"
```

The comparison should thus first compare by string length, then by alphetical order, and then by CaseSensitive.

How could I sort the list this way?

```
Public Class Abbreviation

Implements IComparable

Private _sIn As String = String.Empty
Private _sOut As String = String.Empty
Private _bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False

Public Property Input() As String
    Get
        Return _sIn
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _sIn = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Output() As String
    Get
        Return _sOut
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _sOut = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CaseSensitive() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _bCaseSensitive
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _bCaseSensitive = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal uInput As String, ByVal uOutput As String, ByVal uCaseSensitive As Boolean)

    _sIn = uInput
    _sOut = uOutput
    _bCaseSensitive = uCaseSensitive

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify your code by using automatic properties. The compiler writes the get, set, and backer fields (the private fields). This is the preferred way in recent versions of Visual Studio if there is no extra code in the getter, setter.

Another small detail with your Sub New. It violates encapsulation to set the private fields directly. Always go through the Public Properties. There could be code in the setter that needs to run before storing the data in the private fields. Classes like to keep their data close to the vest in their private fields.

Example of Auto Implemented Properties

```
Public Property Input As String    
Public Property Output As String
Public Property CaseSensitive As Boolean
```

The sort can be done in one line of code using a Linq query.

```
Dim orderedList = From abrev In lstAbreviations Order By abrev.Input.Lenght Descending Select abrev
```

To check the output...

```
For Each abrev As Player In orderedList
      Debug.Print(abrev.Input)
Next
```

Comment: `New` is part of the encapsulation of the Class. It has parameters and the code in the class decides what to do with those parameters that are passed. Key point, setting private fields in `New` does not break encapsulation. Whether there are other efficiencies is a different discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, except the case sensitivity. CaseSensitive should come before CaseSensitive = False.

```
Public Class Abbreviation

Implements IComparable(Of Abbreviation)

Private _sIn As String = String.Empty
Private _sOut As String = String.Empty
Private _bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False

Public Function CompareTo(uOther As Abbreviation) As Integer _
Implements IComparable(Of Abbreviation).CompareTo

    If uOther.Input.Length > Me.Input.Length Then
        Return 1
    ElseIf uOther.Input.Length < Me.Input.Length Then
        Return -1
    Else
        If uOther.Input > Me.Input Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return -1
        End If
    End If

End Function
```